# Running MPI programs on a specified number of cores

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessing, mpi

I am new to MPI programming. I want to run my MPI program on a specified number of cores. I referred to the help option by typing `mpirun --help`. It gave the following output:

> ```
> ...
>
> -c|-np|--np <arg0>       Number of processes to run
>
> ...
>
> -n|--n <arg0>         Number of processes to run
>
> ...
> ```

However, when I referred to [this website](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mpirun), it specifies the following two different things in two different places:

in the introduction:

> mpirun typically works like this
>
> ```
> mpirun -np <number of processes> <program name and arguments>
> ```

and in the options help menu:

```
-np <np>
    - specify the number of processors to run on
```

In this scenario, does `-np` specify the ***number of processes to run or processors to run on***? Moreover, *how do I run my MPI programs on multiple PCs*?

Any help would be appreciated in this regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of -np specifies processes. The number of actual processors that the job runs on depends how you have configured MPI and your computer architecture. If you have mpi setup correctly on your local machine,  `mpirun -np 2 ./a.out` will run two processes on two processors. If your local machine has four cores and you run `mpirun -np 8 ./a.out`, this should run 8 processes with two per processor (which may be sensible if the cores allow multi-threading). Check on `top` to see how many processors are actually used for various cases.

To run on multiple PCs, you will need to specify a list of the PCs network addresses in a host file and start a ring with a process manager like hydra or mpd, e.g. for 8 PCs or nodes `mpd -n 8 -f ~/mpd.hosts`. You will need to setup ssh to use key authentication and install MPI on every PC. There are a number of good tutorials which can walk you through this process (check the tutorials for the version of MPI you are using, probably [MPICH](https://www.mpich.org/) or [openMPI](http://www.open-mpi.org/)).